# How to use Nuitka on my python app?

Tags: python, packaging, nuitka

I have a python app in a directory my_app. There are number of py files in it like a.py, b.py, c.py and so on. I have to run python a.py in order to start my app, but a.py depends on b.py and c.py. Now I want a exe file which can start a.py. I want to use Nuitka to do this. Please help me as I find no relevant documents :(

Comment: In the [User Manual](http://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html) you have some Use Cases from which Use Case 1 or Use Case 2 seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You ought to call the only command form directory my_app:

```
nuitka --standalone --recurse-all --output-dir=deploy-nui a.py
```

You'll get your application into folder **my_app/deploy-nui/a.dist**

Of course before use nuitka you ought to install nuitka:

```
pip install nuitka
```

or

```
pip3 install nuitka
```